# Comparing two sum function in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check that an amount of likes the users received in all their personal pictures is at least twice as large as the number of likes received in the group pictures in which they are tagged.
In case the user is not tagged in any group photo but is tagged in a personal picture that has received at least one like, it will be returned.

My Question is:
  How can I make a comparison between 2 sum functions
Where one result of the sum is returned in the nested query and compared with the external query.
Can I set an auxiliary variable to enter the sum value in it and compare it?
Thanks for the helpers:)

```
 Select distinct UIP.userID
    From tblUserInPersonalPic UIP
    where **sum(UIP.numOfLikes) over (Partition by UIP.userID)*0.5** > 
            (Select distinct U.userID, sum(P.numOfLikes) over (Partition by U.userID)
                                From tblgroupPictures P left outer join 
                                tblUserInGroupPic U On P.picNum=U.picNum
                                group by U.userID,P.numOfLikes,P.picNum)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda hard to know for sure, and of course I can't test my answer,
but I think you can do it with a couple of left joins, group by and having:

```
SELECT Personal.UserId
FROM tblUserInPersonalPic Personal
LEFT JOIN tblUserInGroupPic UserInGroup ON Personal.userID = UserInGroup.UesrId
LEFT JOIM tblgroupPictures GroupPictures ON UserInGroup.picNum = GroupPictures.picNum
GROUP BY Personal.userID
HAVING SUM(GroupPictures.numOfLikes) * 2 <  SUM(Personal.numOfLikes)
```

Please note: When posting sql questions it's always best to provide sample data as DDL + DML (Create table + insert into statements) and desired results, so that who ever answers you can test the answer before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two ctes..pseudo code.Also note distinct in second query will not even work,since you are returning two columns,so i changed it it below,so that you can get that column as well

```
;with tbl1
as
(
select a,sum(col1) as summ
from
tbl1
)
,tbl2
as
(
select userid,sum(Anothersmcol) as sum2
from tbl2

)
select tbl1.columns,tbl2.columns
from
tbl1 t1
join
tbl2 t2
on t1.sumcol>t2.sumcol
```

Comment: That was my initial though as well, but then I started to actually write them and I think a single query can get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use window functions in a `where` clause.  Define it in a subquery:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  sum(...) over (...) as Sum1
        ,       OtherColumn
        from    YourTable
        ) sub
where   Sum1 < (...your subquery...)
```